# AWS Quicksight: Display week as a number, grouped by month and not year

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I need to display Week as number in AWS QuickSight.I understand, we can do this to get the week numbers: In the field wells, click the format option for the date field and on the left side-panel, enter 'w' in the Custom format field.

The issue is this gives the week number in the year. How do I get week number per month?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [calculated fields](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/working-with-calculated-fields.html) to calculate it.

It depends how you define "week of month". In a simple case, if you define first 7 days of a month as *"week 1"*, the second 7 days as *"week 2"*, etc, use this formula:

```
dateDiff(truncDate('MM', mydate), mydate, 'WK') + 1
```

I do a date-diff (in weeks) between first day of month (truncDate) to input-ed date.

Result:

[image: Result]